# Cannot change Ubuntu root password

Tags: ubuntu, root, passwords

I've tried to use this to change my Ubuntu 10.04 password

```
sudo passwd
```

The process goes fine, I type the new password and the get the message on successfull completion. However, nothing actually happens, because on the next chance I have to type the password - old one works.

What do you think?

Comment: You enabled a root password on Ubuntu?  Normally the root account is not login-enabled.  Why did you feel you needed to do that?

Comment: Because I didn't know the difference between my user+sudo and real root before.. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that you have got what you are actually doing; apologies if the following is obvious to you and I'm reading too much or not enough into your question.

`sudo passwd` sets the password for the user `root`. Once you have done this, you can log into your machine with the username `root` and the password you have set (in a terminal anyway, it is probably not allowed at a graphical login). You can also `become` root in a terminal on your desktop by using the command `su -` and entering the password for root.

What will not change is *your* user password, ie the one you use to log in with and the one you use when you use `sudo`.

The difference between "becoming root" and using `sudo` is that if you are going to perform a series of commands that use root priviledges, you can become root and then run the commands at the prompt (the prompt will normally change from a `$` to a `#` and may also change colour to show that you are now the root user) whereas if you stay as yourself and use `sudo`, *each command* you enter needs to be preceeded by `sudo`.

Comment: Neal, thank you very much for the explanation, as I didn't know that! I've done passwd mysername and got the expected result. Thank you!